# memory usage at 100%, more than 10gb

Tags: memory, freeze, monitoring

I currently have some problems with my PC (Win7 x64). 
Every so often, my PC totaly freezes for some seconds / minutes and then sloly comes back to life. I've noticed the RAM usage could be the problem since the task manager showed me that my 12GB of RAM got used up to 100% shortly after and before the machine froze. However, the processes themselfes didn't used much when I checked. Chrome used 1gb, no other process used more.

I've tried to monitor the problem with perfmon to find out what exactly used all the RAM but since the PC froze, the application wasn't able to monitor the values correctly.

Do you have an Idea what application could help me to find the root of this problem? Or does anybody had an comparable problem before?

Thanks in advance.

HijackThis:

```
Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.5
Scan saved at 22:06:27, on 29.08.2014
Platform: Windows 7 SP1 (WinNT 6.00.3505)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v11.0 (11.00.9600.17239)

FIREFOX: 30.0 (en-US)
Boot mode: Normal

Running processes:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\Updater\TBNotifier.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Western Digital\WD Quick View\WDDMStatus.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
C:\Users\WilliamR\AppData\Local\Akamai\netsession_win.exe
C:\Users\WilliamR\AppData\Local\Akamai\netsession_win.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcpackages\VCPkgSrv.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcpackages\VCPkgSrv.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Users\WilliamR\Downloads\HijackThis.exe

R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://www.qvo6.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=cor&from=cor&uid=WDCXWD6400AAKS-22A7B2_WD-WCASY935345253452&ts=1376046135
R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://www.qvo6.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=cor&from=cor&uid=WDCXWD6400AAKS-22A7B2_WD-WCASY935345253452&ts=1376046135
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://www.qvo6.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=cor&from=cor&uid=WDCXWD6400AAKS-22A7B2_WD-WCASY935345253452&ts=1376046135
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://www.qvo6.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=cor&from=cor&uid=WDCXWD6400AAKS-22A7B2_WD-WCASY935345253452&ts=1376046135
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,SearchAssistant = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Local Page = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\blank.htm
R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings,ProxyOverride = *.local;<local>
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
F2 - REG:system.ini: UserInit=userinit.exe
O2 - BHO: Avira SearchFree Toolbar BHO - {41564952-412D-5637-00A7-7A786E7484D7} - "C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\AVIRA-V7\Passport.dll" (file missing)
O2 - BHO: AMD SteadyVideo BHO - {6C680BAE-655C-4E3D-8FC4-E6A520C3D928} - C:\Program Files (x86)\amd\SteadyVideo\SteadyVideo.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In SSV Helper - {761497BB-D6F0-462C-B6EB-D4DAF1D92D43} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\ssv.dll
O2 - BHO: Microsoft Web Test Recorder 10.0 Helper - {876d9f09-c6d6-4324-a2cc-04dd9a4de12f} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.RecorderBarBHO100.dll
O2 - BHO: Microsoft-Konto-Anmelde-Hilfsprogramm - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll
O2 - BHO: DealPly Shopping - {9cf699ca-2174-4ed8-bec1-ba82095edce0} - C:\Program Files (x86)\DealPly\DealPlyIE.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper - {DBC80044-A445-435b-BC74-9C25C1C588A9} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\jp2ssv.dll
O3 - Toolbar: Avira SearchFree Toolbar - {41564952-412D-5637-00A7-7A786E7484D7} - "C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\AVIRA-V7\Passport.dll" (file missing)
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [avgnt] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe" /min
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe ARM] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent for Windows] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe" -minimized
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SwitchBoard] C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SwitchBoard\SwitchBoard.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [AdobeCS6ServiceManager] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\CS6ServiceManager\CS6ServiceManager.exe" -launchedbylogin
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [ApnTBMon] "C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\Updater\TBNotifier.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [StartCCC] "C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe" MSRun
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [LogMeIn Hamachi Ui] "C:\Program Files (x86)\LogMeIn Hamachi\hamachi-2-ui.exe" --auto-start
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [WD Quick View] C:\Program Files (x86)\Western Digital\WD Quick View\WDDMStatus.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [DAEMON Tools Lite] "C:\Program Files (x86)\DAEMON Tools Lite\DTLite.exe" -autorun
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Overwolf] C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\Overwolf.exe -silent
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Akamai NetSession Interface] "C:\Users\WilliamR\AppData\Local\Akamai\netsession_win.exe"
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [GoogleChromeAutoLaunch_059A2383256B3EFA87DD2F9ACE290BB3] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Raptr] C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\raptrstub.exe --startup
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'LOKALER DIENST')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'LOKALER DIENST')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'NETZWERKDIENST')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'NETZWERKDIENST')
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\windows\system32\vsocklib.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\windows\system32\vsocklib.dll
O11 - Options group: [ACCELERATED_GRAPHICS] Accelerated graphics
O18 - Protocol: wlpg - {E43EF6CD-A37A-4A9B-9E6F-83F89B8E6324} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\AlbumDownloadProtocolHandler.dll
O18 - Filter: video/mp4 - {20C75730-7C25-476B-95DC-C65810F9E489} - C:\Program Files (x86)\amd\SteadyVideo\VideoMIMEFilter.dll
O18 - Filter: video/x-flv - {20C75730-7C25-476B-95DC-C65810F9E489} - C:\Program Files (x86)\amd\SteadyVideo\VideoMIMEFilter.dll
O23 - Service: Adobe Acrobat Update Service (AdobeARMservice) - Adobe Systems Incorporated - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\Alg.exe,-112 (ALG) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: AMD External Events Utility - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\atiesrxx.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: AMD FUEL Service - Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Fuel\Fuel.Service.exe
O23 - Service: Avira Planer (AntiVirSchedulerService) - Avira Operations GmbH & Co. KG - C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\sched.exe
O23 - Service: Avira Echtzeit-Scanner (AntiVirService) - Avira Operations GmbH & Co. KG - C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avguard.exe
O23 - Service: Avira Browser-Schutz (AntiVirWebService) - Avira Operations GmbH & Co. KG - C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\AVWEBGRD.EXE
O23 - Service: Ask Aktualisierungsdienst (APNMCP) - APN LLC. - C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\apnmcp.exe
O23 - Service: Apple Mobile Device - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\AppleMobileDeviceService.exe
O23 - Service: Dienst "Bonjour" (Bonjour Service) - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe
O23 - Service: DealPly Live-Dienst (dealplylive) (dealplylive) - DealPly Technologies Ltd - C:\Program Files (x86)\DealPlyLive\Update\DealPlyLive.exe
O23 - Service: DealPly Live-Dienst (dealplylivem) (dealplylivem) - DealPly Technologies Ltd - C:\Program Files (x86)\DealPlyLive\Update\DealPlyLive.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\efssvc.dll,-100 (EFS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\fxsresm.dll,-118 (Fax) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\fxssvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: FlexNet Licensing Service 64 - Flexera Software LLC - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Macrovision Shared\FLEXnet Publisher\FNPLicensingService64.exe
O23 - Service: Google Update-Dienst (gupdate) (gupdate) - Google Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
O23 - Service: Google Update-Dienst (gupdatem) (gupdatem) - Google Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
O23 - Service: LogMeIn Hamachi Tunneling Engine (Hamachi2Svc) - LogMeIn Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\LogMeIn Hamachi\hamachi-2.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\ieetwcollectorres.dll,-1000 (IEEtwCollectorService) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\IEEtwCollector.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: iPod-Dienst (iPod Service) - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files\iPod\bin\iPodService.exe
O23 - Service: @keyiso.dll,-100 (KeyIso) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: LMIGuardianSvc - LogMeIn, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\LogMeIn Hamachi\LMIGuardianSvc.exe
O23 - Service: MIDISPORT Audio Device Monitor (MIDISPORTAudioDevMon) - M-Audio - C:\Program Files (x86)\M-Audio\MIDISPORT\AudioDevMon.exe
O23 - Service: Mozilla Maintenance Service (MozillaMaintenance) - Mozilla Foundation - C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Maintenance Service\maintenanceservice.exe
O23 - Service: @comres.dll,-2797 (MSDTC) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\System32\netlogon.dll,-102 (Netlogon) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: NetLimiter 3 Service (nlsvc) - Locktime Software - C:\Program Files\NetLimiter 3\nlsvc.exe
O23 - Service: PnkBstrA - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\PnkBstrA.exe
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\psbase.dll,-300 (ProtectedStorage) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Protexis Licensing V2 x64 (PSI_SVC_2_x64) - arvato digital services llc - c:\Program Files\Common Files\Protexis\License Service\PsiService_2.exe
O23 - Service: Remote Packet Capture Protocol v.0 (experimental) (rpcapd) - Riverbed Technology, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\rpcapd.exe
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\Locator.exe,-2 (RpcLocator) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\locator.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\samsrv.dll,-1 (SamSs) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\snmptrap.exe,-3 (SNMPTRAP) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\snmptrap.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\spoolsv.exe,-1 (Spooler) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe,-101 (sppsvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\sppsvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Steam Client Service - Valve Corporation - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe
O23 - Service: SwitchBoard - Adobe Systems Incorporated - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SwitchBoard\SwitchBoard.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\ui0detect.exe,-101 (UI0Detect) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\UI0Detect.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vaultsvc.dll,-1003 (VaultSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vds.exe,-100 (vds) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\vds.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: VMware Authorization Service (VMAuthdService) - VMware, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmware-authd.exe
O23 - Service: VMware DHCP Service (VMnetDHCP) - VMware, Inc. - C:\Windows\system32\vmnetdhcp.exe
O23 - Service: VMware USB Arbitration Service (VMUSBArbService) - VMware, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\VMware\USB\vmware-usbarbitrator64.exe
O23 - Service: VMware NAT Service - VMware, Inc. - C:\Windows\system32\vmnat.exe
O23 - Service: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent (vpnagent) - Cisco Systems, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnagent.exe
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\vssvc.exe,-102 (VSS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\vssvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\wbengine.exe,-104 (wbengine) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbengine.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: WD Backup (WDBackup) - Western Digital Technologies, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Western Digital\WD SmartWare\WDBackupEngine.exe
O23 - Service: WD Drive Manager (WDDriveService) - Western Digital Technologies, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\Western Digital\WD Drive Manager\WDDriveService.exe
O23 - Service: WinZiper service (winzipersvc) - Taiwan Shui Mu Chih Ching Technology Limited. - C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZipper\winzipersvc.exe
O23 - Service: @%Systemroot%\system32\wbem\wmiapsrv.exe,-110 (wmiApSrv) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbem\WmiApSrv.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe,-101 (WMPNetworkSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe (file missing)

--
End of file - 14365 bytes
```

Comment: what applications are usually open when this happens ?

Comment: Visual Studio and Chrome. Also Explorer and a WD Application which is currently busy making backUps on an external HDD. I already had those freezes some weeks ago and the WD app is running since yesterday, so I can quite surely say that it's not the source.

Also some of background-apps, but nothing realy important. Thinks like speedfan, antivir,...

Comment: This question's answer depends on many factors and it's vague , so you should scan your system with HijackThis ( sourceforge.net/projects/hjt ) , and put your log of the scan here so we can know what's causing the problem in order to help you.

Comment: Hi, 
I've attached the log.

However, since the freezes are quite irregulare, I don't think that we find something without monitoring the usage. Do you know an app which searches fore strange memory allocs or something like this?

Comment: Your log seems without any unusual problems , i recommend removing your ram , cleaning it , also clean it's slot , but be careful with the ESD , don't use your bare hands, check also your CPU's temperature and fan spin.

Comment: RAMMAp shows you in detail how the RAM is used in Windows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: RamMap doesn't has a record function right? It's hard to check the memory usage when the whole PC is frozen. :(

Comment: It has a save function. Store the data as a RMP file and share this file

Comment: The problem is that I can't use the PC when it's frozen. ;) And as soon as I can normaly save a file, the problem is gone again. That's why I cant just use the task-manager or the resource manager to overlook whats creating the problem...

Comment: make a picture with your smartphone of RAMMap if the PC freezes. Please also post @magicandre1981 so that I get notified when you reply.

Comment: I didn't had the trouble for some days again, which actually makes me worrie more. ;D 

But again: The problem is that the PC starts lagging realy bad and after some seconds freezes completely. In this time, I can't realy do anything with the PC since a mouse klick or key press to switch to a monitor program won't be executed or only after the PC recovers from the freeze.

I've only had the luck once because I had the task manager open while the PC froze so I noticed the huge spike. 

So I can't realy monitor the memory by myself but I need an application which constantly takes a sample.

Comment: I landed on this question while googling "tbnotifier avira ram". I am checking because I noticed that tbnotifier is taking 1GB RAM on my pc (and the pc was turned on only 4 hours ago). Maybe this is a problem also for you?

Comment: Propably not. 
I didn't got the problem for a while now so I think it maybe is temperature relevant after all. (Had this problem mostly over the summer)